# Linear Search method using generics not working

Tags: java, generics

I am a newbie in java. I tried to make a Linear Search class which can take any type and find it in a list.

```
package Client.LinearSearch;

    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LinearSearch<E> {
    public static <E> int Search(ArrayList<E> list, E key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(key)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But when i tried to search using this method, it shows method cannot be applied to the following types.Linear Search was taken from a list of objects and toSearch is user defined

```
List<String>nameList=new ArrayList<>();
            for(Employee employee:employeeList){
                nameList.add(employee.getName());
            }
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String toSearch=sc.nextLine();
LinearSearch<String> stringLinearSearch=new LinearSearch<String>();
int index=stringLinearSearch.Search(nameList,toSearch);
```

![enter image description here][1]

The error message:

```
java: method Search in class Client.LinearSearch.LinearSearch<E> cannot be applied to given types;
 required: java.util.ArrayList<E>,E
  found:    java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E
    (argument mismatch; java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<E>)
```

Comment: How do you declare `nameList` and `toSearch`?

Comment: Please post the error message as text instead of image.

Comment: nameList is made from a list of objects and toSearch is taken via user input
List<String>nameList=new ArrayList<>();
            for(Employee employee:employeeList){
                nameList.add(employee.getName());
            }
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String toSearch=sc.nextLine();

Comment: Bear in mind method names in Java begin lower case and are in camel case

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to loosen up the type for the `list` parameter. You don't necessarily need an `ArrayList`; any old `List` will do. So a method definition like this might help:

```
public static <E> int Search(List<E> list, E key) {
```

As a side-note, returning 0 if the element isn't found makes it look like the element actually *was* found (at index 0). Consider returning something like `-1` (the convention for many `indexOf` functions) instead.